# context.createElement is not a function in fluxible 1.0.x

Tags: reactjs, fluxible

Upgraded the app from fluxible v0.4.x to v1.0.x and all is looking well, except that this error is now happening. `context.createElement is not a function`

The relevant lines of code seem to be:

```
// ...
var app = new Fluxible({
    component: Application
});
// ...
var context = app.createContext();
// ...
React.renderToString(context.createElement());
```

Any thoughts on where to look or what to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`createElementWithContext(context, props);`](https://github.com/yahoo/fluxible/blob/master/packages/fluxible-addons-react/docs/api/createElementWithContext.md) has replaced `context.createElement(props)`. This was to decouple Fluxible core from React.